# Unable to export aspx gridview to .xlsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, xlsx

Hoping someone more knowledgeable with C# can point out where i'm going wrong please.

Being a Powershell scripter and relatively new to C#, I've added a button to my web page that attempts to export the GridView to a .xlsx file and have the browser behave like the file is being downloaded.  I had this working for .xls files, but now need to update it for .xlsx export.

The GridView is a web view of a SQL table.

I've largely modified code that others have posted online to export a GridView to .xlsx, but have never had it working.

Please find the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Bibliography;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using TableCell = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ExportGridToExcel();
    }
        private void ExportGridToExcel()
        {
        
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
                }
            }
            
            string FileName = "DataExport" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
            string FilePath = Path.GetTempPath();
            string FileNameAndPath = "FilePath\\FileName";
            
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            //using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(MyMemoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(MyMemoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))

            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook
                {
                    Sheets = new Sheets()
                };

                var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new SheetData();
                sheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

                Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                uint sheetId = 1;
                if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    sheetId =
                        sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                }

                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "SoTExport" };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                Row headerRow = new Row();

                List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                    Cell cell = new Cell
                    {
                        DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String,
                        CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName)
                    };
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }


                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (DataRow dsrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Row newRow = new Row();
                    foreach (String col in columns)
                    {
                        Cell cell = new Cell
                        {
                            DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String,
                            CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()) //
                        };
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
                workbookPart.Workbook.Save(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            
            }

            
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

When the "Export to Excel" button is clicked, it throws an error stating:
Cannot perform a read/write operation in write-only or read-only modes.
Debugging it, the error is thrown when the line below is executed:

MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

I have tried replacing the line above with:

Response.BinaryWrite(MyMemoryStream.ToArray());

but that gives me a 1KB Excel file with no data in and also doesn't give me the "Save As" dialogue box in Edge.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how the data is supposed to work.  I can see how the spreadsheet object is getting populated by iterating through the GridView/data table, but can't actually see how the memory stream comes into play or why.

Any help or guidance that can be offered would be greatly appreciated as I'm at my wits end now.

Many thanks indeed!

I have tried various other suggestions I have seen online, but as they didn't work, I ended up deleting those lines.
What I expect or hope to happen is that the data table is exported to a .xlsx file, with the data being identical to the data table on the .aspx web page (which is a SQL table) and that the browser gives the Save As dialogue box so that the user can save it where they need to, rather than an automatic download.

Comment: Why you are trying to create a datatable and exporting it to excel? are you trying something like this? https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/415/

Comment: The Web page displays the SQL table much like in your example, but it is all on one web page, not cycling through many.
However, the example you gave exports to .xls format, not .xlsx.  I have a version of the code that exports to .xls, but i need to update the code to export to .xlsx format.

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood your question correctly, your grid is already loaded on the .aspx page and you are trying to download the data from GridView1 at the click of a button, which calls the ExportGridToExcel() method.
Can you please try the code below, you will have to set the the path  and let me know if this solves your problem:

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()  
{  
   Response.Clear();  
   Response.Buffer = true;  
   Response.ClearContent();  
   Response.ClearHeaders();  
   Response.Charset = "";  
   string FileName ="SoTDataExport"+DateTime.Now+".xlsx";  
   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();  
   HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);        
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  
   Response.ContentType ="application/vnd.ms-excel";    
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + FileName);  
   GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;  
   GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;  
   GridView1.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);  
   Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());  
   Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment R_V, but the line: 

Response.ContentType ="application/vnd.ms-excel"; 

outputs .xls format, not .xlsx.